# How to declare something like empty Object/Struct inside Struct?

Tags: go, struct, go-fiber, go-structtag

Hi i am process of learning the Go language, and i want to ask how to create empty Object/Struct as domain model data type? i am using Fiber as my framework and here is the example of what i want to get from golang response api is something like this :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Success registered",
  "data": {
      "first_name": "asdfa",
      "last_name": "asdfa",
      "email": "fadsfa",
      "password": "asdfasfas"
  }
}
```

and here is how i try, here is my responseDto.go :

```
type ResponseDto struct {
    Success bool   `json:"success"`
    Message string   `json:"message"`
    Data    fiber.Map `json:"data"`
}
```

then here is how my controller looked like :

```
func Register(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    user := request.UserRequest{}
    //do something then return

    return c.JSON(models.ResponseDto{
        Success: false,
        Message: "Success registered",
        Data: fiber.Map{
            "data": user,
        },
    })
}
```

then here is the response :

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Success registered",
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "first_name": "asdfa",
      "last_name": "asdfa",
      "email": "fadsfa",
      "password": "asdfasfas"
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see, i will have nested data, but i don't want it to be nested, i want it just one level nested, like my example . How can i achieve it? what data type should i use and how to use it to assign the value?

Answer (score 2):

You have to "convert" user to fiber.Map

```
func Register(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
   user := request.UserRequest{}
   //do something then return

   return c.JSON(models.ResponseDto{
       Success: false,
       Message: "Success registered",
       Data: fiber.Map{
           "user_name": user.Name,
           "user_age": user.Age,
       },
   })
}
```

Or you can change ResponseDto

```
type ResponseDto struct {
   Success bool   `json:"success"`
   Message string   `json:"message"`
   Data    request.UserRequest `json:"data"`
}
```

Comment: good idea about converting, but if i have to convert it manually, it will takes time when i do refactoring in the future. is there a tool or library like mapper for struct to fiber.Map automatically?

Comment: As you can see [fiber.Map](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/f5338266e3f2b67b3a5d68a1ed890f7373ef2064/app.go) is just `map[string]interface{}`. You can make a method for converting `request.UserRequest` to `fiber.Map`. For more general solution read about `reflect` package in Golang.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want nested data, don't nest it. Sorry if this sounds like a tautology, but I'm not sure how else to address it.

Concretely: if the `data` **is** a `request.UserRequest`, add that as struct field:

```
type ResponseDto struct {
    Success bool                `json:"success"`
    Message string              `json:"message"`
    Data    request.UserRequest `json:"data"`
}
```

**But that couples your request and response models.** If you want to avoid that (I would want to), you must put up with having some more verbose code and set the `fiber.Map` entries one by one. No, you can't iterate over struct fields. You can make your code somewhat more expressive by defining a dedicated type:

```
type UserMap fiber.Map

type ResponseDto struct {
    Success bool    `json:"success"`
    Message string  `json:"message"`
    Data    UserMap `json:"data"`
}

resp := ResponseDto{
    Success: false,
    Message: "Success registered",
    Data: UserMap{
        "first_name": user.FirstName,
        // ...and so on
    },
}
```